# Is it possible to retrieve a record from a random file in a CL program?

Tags: ibm-midrange

Suppose there is a physical file whose name is passed to a CL program in parameter. Given the key field names and values are stored in a file and will be read in via RCVF, is it possible to retrieve the given record from the file this way? I want to extract the value of a field from that record in this way. The name of the file, its key list and the corresponding key values cannot be determined at compile time.

I am currently working on a utility for my fellow developers. Of all the functionalities, one of them is to retrieve a record from a file and check the value of one of the fields. There are several files to be checked(and more are coming), and they all have different keys. The file names, their key lists and the field to be returned are all stored in control files. The user will choose the file from the UI, and the CL(or any other language) would use the existing information to retrieve the field value.

As you can see, the usage is not directly for business, but I still want to keep the difficulty of future maintenance as low as I can.

Comment: This is a great question.  I look forward to seeing how many solutions we can get here that will highlight the overlooked dynamic capabilities of the platform.

Comment: Generally speaking, I do not consider CL an appropriate language for the problem as stated.

Comment: @BuckCalabro Then what should be the language here?

Comment: I would use RPG and embedded SQL to satisfy the technical problem described here.  I might have a different answer if I knew what the business problem was.

Comment: @BuckCalabro SQLRPGLE you mean? How?

Comment: I'd use the CLI http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v5r4/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcli%2Frzadpkickoff.htm but dynamically prepared SQL (PREPARE http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v5r4/topic/db2/rbafzmstpreph2.htm#preph2) should work as well.  You build the SELECT statement you need and you FETCH it into the variables you need.

Comment: Since @BuckCalabro raises a point about the appropriateness of a language, can you explain what the intended use of this functionality is?

Answer (score 1):

The [`DCLF`](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v7r1m0/topic/cl/dclf.htm) statement is tied to the file format at compile time.

In theory you should be able to use a generic file at compile time and [`OVRDBF`](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v7r1m0/topic/ddp/rbae5ovrcon.htm) with `LVLCHK(*NO)` to do what you want but it will throw a *CPF0859* unless the compile-time file has a smaller record length than the overridden file.  If you do that though you end up truncating any data that exists past the compile-time length.

The easiest solution will be to do this in RPG with an program described file.

Comment: how is this 'generic' file going to use the key definition of a randomly chosen file?  This does not seem to be solving the requested problem.  With all due respect, my approach is far easier as well. ;)

Comment: Not sure if this one is going to work when record length and key sequences are all different turn by turn.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend REXX.  Your problem is simple in REXX.

It is a dynamic scripting language included with the OS for ages, but widely overlooked.  It allows you to easily script both CL and SQL, building your statements dynamically if you wish.  REXX excels at string handling, and parsing.  In fact, in REXX, everything is a string, even if it is also a numeric value.

You can pass in the name of the file, the key fields(s), the key value(s), and the name of the column(s) to be retrieved.  These parameters can be combined into an SQL statement, and away you go :)

See the [REXX Reference](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v6r1m0/topic/books_web/sc415729.pdf) and the [REXX Programmer's Guide](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v6r1m0/topic/books_web/sc415728.pdf)

Create a source member with type `REXX`, and is not compiled, but interpreted with `STRREXPRC`.

Statements that are not REXX commands, or that evaluate to a string, are executed in an external command environment.  By default, that environment is CL, but you can `ADDRESS` other environments, most notably SQL.

Comment: If you wish, you can easily create a custom CL *CMD to execute your solution directly in CL.

Comment: REXX might end up as my last resort if no feasible alternative could be found. I could use it to achieve my goal, but not sure if my colleagues are going to happily accepted this approach.

Comment: Well I have mixed results with colleagues, so I understand this.  Or actually, the resistance comes more from managers who are reluctant to   depend on their team learning anything.  Most of my colleagues have accepted REXX once I give them a guided tour of its strengths.  

The other factor is that I do not try to promote it as a tool for use in production business applications, but only as a programmers tool for development environments.

Comment: Frankly speaking, no one in my department knows about this approach. Hardly anyone is aware of its existence on AS/400 either. So it could be fairly tricky to introduce such a new concept.

Comment: Once I learned REXX it soon went from my last resort to a first resort for many years.  In as much as you 'think' in a language, I find REXX very easy to think in.

Comment: If this is just an adhoc tool for developers, they dont necessarily need to worry about what's inside the black box, just that it works nicely and meets their needs.  (If it is going into production, that might be a different issue.) I have many of these tools.  Most of my colleagues don't care what's inside, they just want to use the tool.  If they want to build tools like it, I am more than happy to give them a tutorial.  I've never had a manager who objected, as long as REXX scripts didn't go into production, or need to be supported by anyone else.

Comment: There probably should always be more developers on staff (in an IBM systems site) that are familiar with REXX than ones that are not. E.g., if a staff only has three developers, then at least two should be comfortable in REXX. It is, after all, IBM's defined SAA procedures language. It's been on every system in the AS/400 line since the first couple OS/400 Version 1 releases, even ones with no compiler LPPs and no SQL Dev Kit. REXX would be the easiest language to use to get this question handled.

Comment: I wish REXX had caught on like that in the AS/400 community.  Mainframe REXX has grown and evolved over the years, and reportedly can outperform COBOL, due to faster IO.  PC's have gotten NetREXX, and OORexx.  But REXX/400 has been "stablilized", and I don't recall seeing any significant changes since it was introduced.  And IBM rarely sinks development effort (ie $$) into areas that it's customer base does not seem interested in.

Comment: If IBM would open-source it, or if anybody ported OORexx to PASE, we might see some interest pop up again.  But the reality is that most of the existing customer base is not very interested in learning languages or technologies in general unless given strong incentive.  Perl & Python have been available for OS/400, yet how much development is done with them.  Or even Java & PHP.  PowerRuby is gaining some coverage, along with Rails, and may gain some traction.  But history shows us that merely being a "better technology" does not always guarantee success.

Answer (score 1):

Another dynamic approach is to pass the file name and key field names as variables into a QM Query.  This could be done via CL, or easier in REXX.

I use a generic QM query against a dynamic filename, with a dynamic number of group by fields.

```
SELECT  &FLDS, int(count(*)) AS TALLY
  FROM  &FILE                             
  GROUP BY &FLDS                          
  ORDER BY &FLDS
```

This query underlies a command I created, called VALUES, which lists the values of a given field (or fields) in some file, as well as how often it occurs.

```
VALUES FILE(CUSTMAST) FLDS('CTYPE') 
VALUES FILE(CUSTMAST) FLDS('CSTATE, CTYPE')
```

The first command shows all the values of CTYPE in the CUSTMAST table. The next shows how many of each type occur in each state.

The difficulty would be how do you return any answer back to your CL.  If you are satisfied with simply displaying the results on the screen, this is fine.  Or you could direct the output to a file.  But even in this method REXX will help you ;-)

Comment: I thought about using QMQRY before. The problem is that I need the field value to be accessible for further processing in the CL program, and QMQRY is not so flexible when the number of key fields is known (there could be a lot in a file in my application, I can tell you that).

Comment: I added an example to show that multiple fields are ok in QMQuery

Comment: The length of &FLDS parameter is still limited by 55 characters, right? And there are files with keys added up longer than this. You could say that I just need to add one more, say &FLDS2. And besides, I still need the result to be return to the program somehow.

Comment: In my example, &FLDS contains the names of the columns, so the length of the names is limited to 55 chars.  If you needed more you could use something like &FLDS1&FLDS2&FLDS3&FLDS4, which would let you specify a set of column names (and separating commas) up to 220.  If you are using system column names (ie DDS names limited to 10 chars) then this would allow at least 20 key fields.  Need more? Just use more QM substitution variables.

Answer (score 1):

You want an answer returned to your CL program.  Let's assume for now that the type of answer you are looking for can fit into a single return type, let's say numeric, but character could be implemented as an alternate interface.

You can have an SQL ILE RPG program that dynamically PREPAREs its SQL statements, based on the input parameters, which would include file name, column names to use, etc.

Comment: Is it going to work if the number of keys varies case by case?

Comment: Simplest way -- you pass your list of key field names as one string, delimiting the column names with commas.  You can build your SQL statement with this string.

Comment: If you will be [creating your own CL command](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v7r1m0/index.jsp?topic=%2Frbam6%2Fcmdinfodoc.htm), then in your [PARM command](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v7r1m0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcl%2Fparm.htm) you can specify a maximum number of values allowed.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but why would one want to?  The fundamental problem is that CL is not intended for database operations, whereas a language like RPG is.  Both RPG and CL have a drawback when it comes to fully dynamic file operations: they are strongly typed languages.  This means that you would need to declare the data types you want to return from the file *in advance*.  Which is a bit of a problem for truly dynamic file I/O.  The classic answer to this problem (file not known at compile time) is to write a tool that creates the processing programs for you.

Provide the tool (which can and should be a CL command that you write!) with the file name, key structure, fields to retrieve, etc. and then the tool uses the proper APIs to extract the field definitions from the file and then goes on to actually write the CL source, which it then compiles and then CALLs for you.  Presumably, there is some more or less standard business processing that happens with the fields from these disparate files; the tool should write that too.

Comment: We can write CL programs to copy files around, clear them, or do all sorts of things to them, even though the name of the file can be passed in as a parameter. 
 
Here is a question that pushes the traditional things we do with the language.  Does that mean it shouldn't be done in CL?  Or can we help push against the boundaries to promote new functionality and help make it accessible to the community?  I say why not?

That said, @BuckCalabro you are not entirely off the mark either.  A dynamic scripting language such as REXX would better fit the task at hand.  :-)

Comment: G.T. what do you want to do with this capability you are asking about?  This may help determine the best approach.

Comment: Yes, yes, I am fully aware of the fact that neither CL nor RPG is designed to handle dynamic file operation. I have chosen CL here because it offers slightly more (not too much though) flexibility over RPG. This is the first time I am working on dynamic file operation, and this has never been done in my department before. I am here to explore a possible, elegant solution, yet it has to be acceptable to the department. I would not say creating the program source at run time is a bad idea, but there are quite a lot to be check in one go interactively so I don't want too much compilation here.

Comment: If you are worried about compile times, simply keep the generated programs around and only invoke the create/compile routine when you get a new combination of file/field you want to work with.

Comment: This could end up littering the system with a multitude of compiled programs, some portion of which might never be used again.  While dynamic solutions can handle static problems, static solutions are generally not a good match to a dynamic problem.  (but what is the problem??)

Comment: I have updated the question with a simple description of the thing I am working on. Please check.

Comment: @Buck : I've argued forever that CL is not intended as a database language, but I'm switching this time to say "Why not? (Assuming V5R4 and later.)" If CL is presented that way, we should also include C with CL. Now, I'd also normally say C isn't a 'database' language, but that doesn't stop it from being used that way. As of V5R4, ILE CL has access to all of the same database I/O functions that C has. And if that's not sufficient, the SQL CLI APIs also work. Once some initial basic procedures are written, they can be used over and over. Dynamic file handling then becomes almost easy.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds as though you want to write DSPDTA in CL.

CL lacks almost everything needed to make this happen, but CL is easily extended with commands that you write.  To that end, write several RPG programs (to satisfy your colleagues) that implement the file I/O functionality you need.  Wrap these RPG programs in CL commands that you write.  Some ideas to get you started:

- Declare file
- Retrieve field information
- Open file
- Set key
- Retrieve record
- Set CL variable from file field
- Close file